# How to return ALL events in a Google Calendar without knowing whether it is a timed or all day event

Tags: events, python-2.7, google-calendar-api

Now, I'm working on making a program in Python that can pull events from all the calendars in my Google account; however, I'm trying to make the program potentially as commercial as possible.  With that said, it's quite simple to customize the code for myself, when I know that all the US Holidays events attached to my calendar are all day events, so I can set up a simple if statement that checks if it's a Holiday calendar and specify the events request as such:

```
def get_main_events(pageToken=None):
  events = gc_source.service.events().list(
    calendarId=calendarId,
    singleEvents=True,
    maxResults=1000,
    orderBy='startTime',
    pageToken=pageToken,
    ).execute()
  return events
```

So, that works for all day events.  After which I'd append the results to a list and filter it to get only the events I want.  Now getting events from my primary calendar is a bit easier to specify the events I want because they're generally not all day events, just my work schedule so I can use:

```
now = datetime.now()
now_plus_thirtydays = now + timedelta(days=30)
def get_main_events(pageToken=None):
  events = gc_source.service.events().list(
    calendarId=calendarId,
    singleEvents=True,
    maxResults=1000,
    orderBy='startTime',
    timeMin=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00'),
    timeMax=now_plus_thirtydays.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00'),
    pageToken=pageToken,
    ).execute()
  return events
```

Now, the problem I run into with making the program available for commercial use, as well as myself, is the above will ONLY return NON-all day events from my primary calendar.  I'd like to find out if there's a way - if so, how - to run the get events request and return ALL results whether they're all day or if they're just a timed event that takes place in a portion of the day.  In addition part of this issue is that in another part of the code where I print the results I would need to use:

```
print event['start']['date']
```

for an all day event, and:

```
print event['start']['dateTime']
```

for a non all day event.

So, since 'dateTime' wont work on an all day event, I'd like to figure out a way to set it up so that I can evaluate whether an event is all day or not.  i.e. "if said event is an all day event, use event['start']['date'], else use event['start']['dateTime']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, through much testing, and finding a way to use a log feature to see what error was happening with:

```
print event['start']['date']
```

vs:

```
print event['start']['dateTime']
```

I found that I could use the error result to my advantage using 'try' and 'except'.

Here is the resulting fix:

First the initial part as earlier with the actual query to the calendar:

```
now = datetime.now()
now_plus_thirtydays = now + timedelta(days=30)
def get_calendar_events(pageToken=None):
    events = gc_source.service.events().list(
        calendarId=cal_id[cal_count],
        singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime',
        timeMin=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00'),
        timeMax=now_plus_thirtydays.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-00:00'),
        pageToken=pageToken,
        ).execute()
    return events
```

Then the event handling portion:

```
# Events Portion
    print "Calendar:  ", cal_summary[cal_count]
    events = get_calendar_events()
    while True:
        for event in events['items']:
            try:
                if event['start']['dateTime']:
                    dstime = dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['dateTime'])
                    detime = dateutil.parser.parse(event['end']['dateTime'])
                    if dstime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') == detime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'):
                        print event['summary'] + ": " + dstime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + " " + dstime.strftime('%H%M') + "-" + detime.strftime('%H%M')
                        # Making a list for the respective items so they can be iterated through easier for time comparison and TTS messages
                        if cal_count == 0:
                            us_holiday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                        elif cal_count == 1:
                            birthday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                        else:
                            life_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                    else:
                        print event['summary'] + ": " + dstime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') + " @ " + dstime.strftime('%H%M') + " to " + detime.strftime('%H%M') + " on " + detime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                        # Making a list for the respective items so they can be iterated through easier for time comparison and TTS messages
                        if cal_count == 0:
                            us_holiday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                        elif cal_count == 1:
                            birthday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                        else:
                            life_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                else:
                    return
            except KeyError:
                dstime = dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['date'])
                detime = dateutil.parser.parse(event['end']['date'])
                print event['summary'] + ": " + dstime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                # Making a list for the respective items so they can be iterated through easier for time comparison and TTS messages
                if cal_count == 0:
                    us_holiday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                elif cal_count == 1:
                    birthday_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))
                else:
                    life_list.append((dstime, event['summary']))

        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
        if page_token:
            events = get_calendar_events(page_token)
        else:
            if cal_count == (len(cal_id) - 1):  # If there are no more calendars to process
                break
            else:  #Continue to next calendar
                print "-----"
                cal_count += 1
                print "Retrieving From Calendar:  ", cal_summary[cal_count]
                events = get_calendar_events()
```

Comment: +1 for realizing try / except utility in this situation, and that google returns differing formats for all day events and just appointments.  :)